# Finding better fitting constants parameters of a function for a given dataset

Tags: python, optimization, mathematical-optimization, curve-fitting

Supposing that I have a set of data, and I know that a given function `foo` might fit that data depending on three tuning parater, which we will call: alpha1,alpha2,alpha3, and they are all constants. So, I have a set of real data, which was generated with the `foo` function for the given example, and I want to find out which are the values of the constant parameters mentioned.

So in other words, I want to find which are the value of each constant of my function that would fit the function to my data. Here is a very simple code example which might help you to better understanding what I am trying to achieve:

```
data = [ 0, 11.4, 22.8, 34.2, 45.6,  57,  68.4, 79.8, 91.2, 102.6, 114]

# Function in which I want to find the constant alpha1, alpha2 and alpha3. x is a variable.
def foo(alpha1,alpha2,alpha3,x): 
    y = (3*alpha1 + 2*alpha2 + alpha3)*x
    return y
```

This is a made up example, nothing compared to the situation in which I want to apply a solution, which is quite non-linear and involves many more variables. Also important to have in mind that I know the values of the variables for each data point `x` for each datapoint. In my case, it simply from 0 to 9.

As I generated the data manually, I know that the value of the parameters are:

```
alpha1 = 2.5
alpha2 = 1.2
alpha3 = 1.5
```

This is of course a very simples example which is made up just to better illustrate my question in case someone is willing to show some code. Performing some sort of mesh with different values of the constant and also a minimization function might work as well but it would take ages for a complex scenario. Therefore, I would like to ask if there is any library or algorithm that could be helpful in achieving a solution.

Comment: you could try googling something like *python linear regression*. Depending on what the function `foo` looks like, you might want to skip the *linear* part.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis thanks for the tip. Edited the question to make it more clear in that sense

Comment: Have a look at [`scipy.optimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html) and maybe packages like [scikit-optimize](https://scikit-optimize.github.io/) or the [hyper-parameter optimizers in scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#hyper-parameter-optimizers).

Comment: Looks to me that all coefficients are indistinguishable. I.e., we can regress `y=a1*x1+a2*x2` without a problem (with the usual caveats), but something like `y=(a1+a2)x` is problematic.